# Получить имя исполняемого файла (.ipynb) в jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня python 3.6. пользуюсь jupyter notebook. Не могу получить имя файла, который сейчас запущен.

Нашел два варианта:

1. `__file__` - но этот вариант работает для python 2.7. Выдает 
   `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`
2. `sys.argv[0]` - этот вариант дает имя интерпретатора, который запущен, а не файла.

Comment: что вы под "исполняемым файлом" в контексте jupyter notebook понимаете? Это интерактивное окружение (то есть такие вещи как `inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).filename` вернут фиктивное имя типа: `<ipython-input-5-6b90aba20365>` (в обычном Python REPL это вернуло что-нибудь вроде `'<stdin>'`). Что вы хотите с этим именем делать после?

Comment: related: [Identify notebook file being run](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1000) и [How do I get the current IPython Notebook name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12544056/4279) (там несколько решений разной степени применимости для разных задач)

Comment: Да, нашел там нужный ответ, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%%javascript
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('nb_name = "' + IPython.notebook.notebook_name + '"')
```

После выполнения ячейки в переменной `nb_name` будет имя запущенного ноутбука.

Answer (score 0):

Выводит полный путь к файлу

```
import inspect
print(inspect.stack()[0][1])
```

или можно просто вывести название файла

```
import os
print(os.path.basename(__file__))
```

Comment: `print(inspect.stack()[0][1])`
В это случае выдает:
`<ipython-input-15-f9a6be03bf97>`, может как-то раскодировать?

Comment: `print(os.path.basename(__file__))` В этом случае все равно ругается  и пишет:
`NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`. Может я должен еще что-то написать? Или может это связано с тем, что файл из которого я запускаю не .py, а .ipynb?

Comment: @RudolfMorkovskyi, `.ipynb` - это по сути не модуль python, а скорее сессия интерактивного режима интерпретатора. Средствами именно Python скорее всего его имя не получить. Возможно у jupyter есть какие-то свои встроенные переменные, нужно смотреть.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
%%javascript
var name = IPython.notebook.notebook_name;
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('nb_name = "' + name + '"')
```

Это была первая ячейка. Во второй например можно просто вывести переменную `nb_name`, полученную ранее, либо делать с ней что угодно.

Comment: Это по сути совпадает с ответом от Rudolf Morkovskyi, просто записано немного по-другому.